# Residue from boiling pork sausage

Tags: boiling, sausages

When boiling sausage, I notice a gray, foamy residue that floats on top of the water. I was told that this is unhealthy to eat and should be removed.  Is this true? Does anyone know what this foam is?

[image: This is the foam (don't mind the olive oil)]

[image: sausage (post foam-removal)]

Comment: See this question: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/20390/why-skim-scum-from-the-surface-of-a-simmering-stock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the foam is made of water soluble proteins from when you have cooked the sausages. It may not look nice, or even taste nice, but wont kill you.